# Loop over a curl command throguh a text file using sed

Tags: json, bash, shell

I have a curl commadn that will run through a GitHub runner, the file `export.sh` looks like:

```
while read -r auth0 &&  read -r roles <&3; do
    curl --request POST \
      --url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/USER_ID/roles' \
      --header 'authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
      --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      --header 'content-type: application/json' \
      --data '{ "roles": [ "ROLE_ID" ] }'
done < final-user-id.txt 3<final-id.txt
```

I have a file `final-user-id.txt`, that is like this:

```
Jack
Amy
Colin
```

I also have a file `final-id.txt`:

```
role_1
role_2
role_3
```

I want to run `export.sh` in such a way that every time it picks up a new variable from `final-user-id.txt` and replace it with `auth0` and `"ROLE_ID"` be replaced with the contents of `final-id.txt` So the fist output would be:

```
while read -r auth0 &&  read -r roles <&3; do
    curl --request POST \
      --url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/Jack/roles' \
      --header 'authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
      --header 'cache-control: no-cache' \
      --header 'content-type: application/json' \
      --data '{ "roles": [ "role_1" ] }'
done < final-user-id.txt 3<final-id.txt
```

So on and so forth depending on the number of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r auth0 && IFS= read -r roles <&3; do
  echo curl --request POST \
    --url "https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/$auth0/roles" \
    --header "authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    --header "cache-control: no-cache" \
    --header "content-type: application/json" \
    --data "{ 'roles': [ '$roles'] }"
done < final-user-id.txt 3<final-id.txt
```

Output

```
curl --request POST --url https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/Jack/roles --header authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN --header cache-control: no-cache --header content-type: application/json --data { 'roles': [ 'role_1'] }
curl --request POST --url https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/Amy/roles --header authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN --header cache-control: no-cache --header content-type: application/json --data { 'roles': [ 'role_2'] }
curl --request POST --url https://YOUR_DOMAIN/api/v2/users/Colin/roles --header authorization: Bearer MGMT_API_ACCESS_TOKEN --header cache-control: no-cache --header content-type: application/json --data { 'roles': [ 'role_3'] }
```

---

- Although I suggest to use a different `fd` for `final-user-id.txt` just i case `curl` is using/consuming `stdin`.
- Remove the `echo` if you're satisfied with the output.

---

Since you're using `bash` as mentioned by `@DennisWilliamson` the builtin `read` command has the `-u` flag. so the first line could be written as:

```
while IFS= read -ru3 auth0 && IFS= read -ru4 roles ; do
```

And the last line should be written like:

```
done 3<final-user-id.txt 4<final-id.txt
```

Comment: `read` has `-u` for specifying a file descriptor.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson, right, I was just copy pasting what the OP has.

Comment: Only query of mine is that while your code produces in single quotes my use case is in double quotes, anyway around that? Can it be like this:
--data '{ "roles": [ "role_1" ] }'

Comment: @learner, single quotes would not expand shell variables, you could try escaping the doubles quotes inside the double quotes. try: `--data "{ \"roles\": [ \"$roles\" ] }"`

Comment: Yes, it populates correctly but the data part is in single quotes, if you check my original question. Thanks again for the help.